# Is heap memory freed after closing application?

Tags: java, memory-management, heap-memory

If i create objects in the heap and i don't delete, when i close application that memory is blocked for other applications or simply it is free?. In general it's the same for c++, java and so and for all S.O?

i have knowledge about garbage collector, and delete from C++, the only question is if i don't free the memory i use in the heap if that memory is stuck (until reset the device) for others applications or not). It can be a silly question but really i don't read a clear response.

Thank you!

Edit: In that post it seems to be that all allocated memory heap is released by each s.o independent of languaje/s.o. Is it correct?

Comment: You should read and learn about how garbage collector work in `Java`

Comment: Memory is released as soon as the application is closed assuming you have not invoked any native process.

Comment: There is no "delete" operation in Java.  Except in specialized circumstances it's all automatic.

Comment: An application in any language - C, C++, Java, C#, Objective-C, Pascal, Perl, etc -- will release all RAM storage it was using when the application ends.  And in any language if you create a file (and don't put it in a "temporary" directory, eg) it will persist after the application ends.  (As others have stated, this is done by the OS, not the language runtime.)

Comment: @HotLicks - Suppose I open a socket connection and my app is killed, the connection will still persist because there is someone at the other end.. So, there *might* be a resource leak. The OS will slowly *but not immediately* take care of such things.

Comment: @TheLostMind - Yep, but eventually the resources will be cleaned up, in any realistic scenario for an unsophisticated app.

Answer (score 0):

Heap memory will be released after closing the application, marked as free.
Some handlers like file open handler may exist for a while depending on the system

Comment: `Heap memory will be released after closing the application` not really. If there is shared memory objects those are not remove.

Comment: What's a "shared object"? Do you mean a native peer?

Comment: Many native calls could have been made. Ultimately, its not the JVM but the OS that can close file descriptors and other system level resources.

Comment: Shared object are in the system heap, not the application. And yes, it will be kept unless you release it manually @bbalchev

Comment: How often do we use shared objects? For all practical cases, when a process is terminated the Operating system itself frees up all the resources which includes the Data Segment (heap memory as it's commonly known)